# Is there any way to Customize the 'SiteEdit Enabled Sites ' list on CME

Tags: 2011, cme, gui-extensions

In our environment we have almost 100 sites that are edited via SiteEdit, when we moved to 2011 they have this handy list out on the First Tab with all the sites, but its pretty gnarly...

Has anyone found a way to customize this landing page so we can better organize this site list?

[image: Too many SiteEdit sites :-(]
Right now the Tridion UI just orders them based on the entries into the SiteEdit web.config.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar requirement using 2013 & XPM (I am assuming it is the same structure), and after trailing through JavaScript files and decompiling several DLL's I found that this list comes from some SiteEdit 2009 leftovers.

First the code looks for a registry key specifying the location of the SiteEdit config file. This did not exist with my XPM install, so I created it.

```
(64Bit Key)    
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Tridion\SiteEdit2009 
SiteEditPath: C:\Tridion\SiteEdit 2009\
```

This key then tells the dashboard where to look for the config file, which contains the list of Editable sites

```
  <siteMappings>
    <siteMapping proxyPattern="http://staging.domain.com" stagingUrl="" excludeHeaders="Authorization|Content-Type|If-None-Match" />
  </siteMappings>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

SDL Tridion dashboard is extensible and you have complete control over it to enhance the editor's overall experience.

You can find useful information [here](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/dashboard-extension). A community extension is also available for download [here](https://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/example_ui.aspx). Hope it helps!

Comment: The dashboard itself is extensible, but I don't think that part is extensible.

Comment: It is possible with GUI extension. We have done this in our implementations. For each website and its site edit website you can create links.